# What does "[::]:port number" mean?

Tags: command-line, cmd, ip

I am running netstat -an command in cmd. For some records I am getting [::]:port number in place of ip address. What does it mean ?

[image]

Comment: It's an IPv6 address. In a way, it's equivalent to IPv4's `0.0.0.0:port`.

Comment: That's not "in command prompt." That's in the netstat output.

Comment: [If a host listens for incoming connection on this address, it means that the host and/or its application is listening on all interfaces belong to that host.](http://www.ipuptime.net/Unspecified.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It means listening in all interfaces for those ports.